# How can I get rid of the paddings and margins that come with the webform?

Tags: webforms

What I did was use `position: absolute` to have them the way I want, but that is probably not a good idea. I tried to put padding and margin 0 everywhere, but Drupal seems to override my CSS or something.

Comment: have you tried margin:0px !important; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming D7,

You can use [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) through a node or page template and add in your own styling that way.  That should get loaded last.  [drupal_static_reset()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static_reset/7) can clear out css that may be conflicting if you encounter stubborness.

Also... clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can override Drupals styling rules. Just use your browsers (Chrome, Firefox) developer tools to inspect elements for whats styling rules they have. Then override them in your themes stylesheet(s).